# Function definition to use across project Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, function, c++-cli, definition

Trying to start up again with Visual C++, using 2010 Express edition.

Trying to figure out something.

If define a function in the `Project.cpp` file, why can't I use it in the `Form1.h` file, specifically the private: `System::Void Form1_Load`?

I get this error:

```
1>c:\users\boss\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\second\second\Form1.h(94): error C3861: 'Function': identifier not found
```

Is there any way to define a function so it can be used anywhere?

in Form1.h:

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->txtMain->Text += FunctionX("Data");
    this->txtMain->SelectionStart = this->txtMain->Text->Length;
}
```

in Project.cpp:

```
std::string FunctionX(std::string message) {
    // other code here
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Sounds it is C++/clr

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a forward declaration and a marshal_as for the native to CLI conversion

Comment: I changed the project properties from /cls:pure to /clr, everything else works fine. if I change it to no clr support, I get 50 other errors.

Comment: Where would I forward declare? I Put "std::string FunctionX(std::string message)" in Form1.h, resulting in a dozen different errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
extern std::string FunctionX(std::string message);
this->txtMain->Text += msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(FunctionX("Data"));
this->txtMain->SelectionStart = this->txtMain->Text->Length;
}
```

This works! Thanks for the tips.